# mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/kafka/config': Permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, persistent-volumes

I have tried to deploy Kafka in k8s, so I need to persist its volume with hostpath, but when the volume configuration adds to the deployment file, this error shows in Kafka pod, and the pod state becomes Crashloopbackoff:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/bitnami/config’: Permission denied
```

I think I have to change permission so the pod can create this file.

Deployment.yml:

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-broker
  name: kafka-broker
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-broker
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER
          value: "yes"
        - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
          value: "1"
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zookeeper-service:2181
        - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
          value: PLAINTEXT://:9092
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: PLAINTEXT://:9092
        image: bitnami/kafka
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kafka-broker
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kafka-data
          readOnly: false
          mountPath: "/bitnami/kafka"
      volumes:
      - name: kafka-data
        hostPath:
          path: /data/kafka-data
```

Comment: the question is about **/bitnami/kafka** but the error is about **/bitnami/mariadb**
do you have a /bitnami/mariadb containers also ?

Comment: @LEGALLBenoît, thank you for mentioning that. I made a mistake and edited it. My problem is about Kafka.

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the problem by changing the path (where I mount the pod data )ownership on the worker servers  with this command:

```
sudo chown -R 1001:1001 /data/kafka-data
```

But I think this solution is not bestpractice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set

```
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1001
    runAsGroup: 1001
    fsGroup: 1001
```

in your deployment config ?

Bitnami images are non-root user, and required user 1001
Same for mounted volumes (=> fsGroup)
See https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#persisting-your-data